# When will BSD sockets API accept return?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am a newbie in network programming. By reading UNP, I know that TCP sockets uses two queues to preserve the TCP connection, one for "Not established", one for "established". In client process, the API "connect" will return when the client receives the ACK for the SYN. Now, I am curious about , in server, when the accept API will return? Will it return when server receives SYN(The first TCP segment in three-way handshake) or ACK for (SYN + 1)(the third TCP segment in three-way handshake)?

Comment: It will return when it receives the ACK, i.e. when the handshake is completed.

Comment: To put that another way, it will only return when there is a completed connection.